# I cannot search/find any applications in the Dash on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, updates, unity-dash

Its been a while since I booted my Ubuntu (12.04), but when i did I had several updates (over 100) and  I installed them along with rebooting.

These updates seemed to mess with my video driver but I seemed to have fixed this.

My problem is that my applications do not show  anywhere. I can open them via terminal or if there are shortcuts (such as on the toolbar) but if I hit Super and go to Apps, there is nothing.

This is true if I hit Super and search any app name nothing will come back (except for files).

I need help to understand what happened! Also for some reason I can't upgrade to 12.10 (I assume because I have 12.04 and not 12.04.1, which I don't understand how to get).

Comment: I did fix the update to 12.10 thing, I will check if I can see them after it finishes.

Comment: Please confirm if upgrading to 12.10 resolved your issue (as suggested in your comment.  This will enable us to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll check that when I get home, they are all here on my laptop and thus it works on my laptop (at work for a bit) but if they are missing in the folder when I get home, what can I do to fix it? Would the 12.10 upgrade "reset" those and make it work? My desktop machine is upgrading while I am here.

Answer (score 0):

navigate to /usr/share/applications. Are your application .desktop files in there?

I think that is what dictates whether they show up.